# How can i make a general coding from my function?

Tags: python

I am trying to instantiate two variables, one for the minimum value and one for the minimum index and then iterate through the indices of the list and compute the value of

```
difference = sum(beginning) - sum(end)
```

for each index.

If `difference` is less than the minimum stored value, set the minimum value to `difference` and the minimum index to `index`, and finally return the slices found from using the minimum index.

For example:

```
a=[8,-1,6]
```

Slices found: `[8,-1]` and `[6]`

My code does what I want for a list of 3 values, but I do not know how to make it work for a longer list like

```
a = [-11,15,14,12,12]
```

which should return `[-11,15,14], [12,12]`

My Code:

```
def row(a):
    b = a[0] - sum(a[1:])
    c = sum(a[:-1]) - a[-1]

    if b <= c:
        return a[:1], a[1:]
    else:        
        return a[:-1], a[-1:]
```

Edit:

I actually need to minimize the *absolute value* of `sum(beginning) - sum(end)`.

Comment: I read it twice and I understood absolutely nothing

Comment: Your 2nd `return` will never be executed.

Comment: 1). It looks like you left the `else:` out between your two return statements. 2). Why is `[-11, 15, 14], [12, 12]` the result for `[-11,15,14,12,12]`? It has a difference of -6, but `[-11], [15, 14, 12, 12]` has a difference of -64, which is the minimum difference.

Comment: well if you sum -11,15,14 and then sum 12,12 and subtract the two results you will get 6 which the minimum value after getting subtracting

Comment: sum of 12,12 - sum of -11,15,14

Comment: `sum(beginning) - sum(end)` is `sum([ -11,15,14]) - sum([12,12])` which equals -6. But `sum([-11]) - sum([15, 14, 12, 12])` = -64, which is smaller than -6. Or are you looking for the smallest _absolute_ difference?

Comment: i am sorry its sum(end) - sum(beginning)

Comment: So why isn't `[-11, 15, 14, 12], [12]` the solution? It has a difference of 12-30 = -18, which is smaller than 6.

Comment: Sorry then it's the same as you discribed in the last comment

Comment: Well, we got there in the end. : ) I have edited your question to make it more useful for future readers.

Comment: thanks i just knew it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your code expanded to take a list of any size. It creates a list of tuples containing the slice index and the absolute difference between the beginning sum and the end sum, and then uses the built-in `min` function to find which absolute difference is the minimum.

This code will run on Python 2 or Python 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def row(seq):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        start = seq[:i]
        end = seq[i:]
        startsum = sum(start)
        endsum = sum(end)
        diff = abs(startsum - endsum)
        print(start, end, startsum, endsum, diff)
        result.append((diff, i))

    t = min(result)
    print('min', t)
    i = t[1]
    return seq[:i], seq[i:]


a = [-11, 15, 14, 12, 12]

print(a)
print(row(a))
```

**output**

```
[-11, 15, 14, 12, 12]
[-11] [15, 14, 12, 12] -11 53 64
[-11, 15] [14, 12, 12] 4 38 34
[-11, 15, 14] [12, 12] 18 24 6
[-11, 15, 14, 12] [12] 30 12 18
min (6, 3)
([-11, 15, 14], [12, 12])
```

The `print` calls are just to show that the function is doing what we expect it to. We can make the function more compact, like this:

```
def row(seq):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        diff = abs(sum(seq[:i]) - sum(seq[i:]))
        result.append((diff, i))

    i = min(result)[1]
    return seq[:i], seq[i:]
```

We can use a list comprehension to make the function more efficient by calculating the cumulative sums in a loop, and then calculating the minimum absolute difference using a generator expression:

```
def row(seq):
    allsums = []
    total = 0
    for u in seq:
        total += u
        allsums.append(total)

    i = min((abs(2*u - total), i) for i, u in enumerate(allsums[:-1], 1))[1] 
    return seq[:i], seq[i:]
```

The values in the `allsums` list correspond to the `startsum` values in the first version, the corresponding `endsum` values are simply `total - startsum`. So the difference `startsum - endsum` is `startsum - (total - startsum)` = `2*startsum - total`, which becomes `2*u - total` in the generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly understand your code, but I *think* this is what you mean ...

```
ds = [-11,15,14,12,12]
def diff(ds, i): return abs(sum(ds[:i]) - sum(ds[i:]))

# Find the differences by position
diffList = [diff(ds, i) for i in range(len(ds))]

# Print the minimum value, and the index of the position ...
print min(diffList), diffList.index(min(diffList))
```

Comment: I am trying to run it but i got an error missing one requirement  i, what is the parameter  i ?

Comment: Where exactly? There is `i` in the line `[diff(ds, i) for i in range(len(ds))]`, as, which is defined in the `for` statement. And there is `i` as the input parameter of a function. Both should be exactly defined ...